# Openstack instance is not reachable due to metadata issue in liberty

Tags: metadata, openstack

Getting this error in instance log. I could not seek out any errors in nova or neutron log. 
Checked with all configuration and everything is fine.

url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [50/120s]: request error [(, 'Connection to 169.254.169.254 timed out. (connect timeout=50.0)')]

Anyone could help whats the actual error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

**Probable Reason1:-**

I guess you are running instances with GUI installed on them. When you install GUI on an instance(ubuntu/centos or whatever), they bring in a bunch of different services. Specially, in ubuntu, a service named "avahi" gets added and started which adds a route of 169.254/16 on the instance. This starts causing the issue as now the instance thinks that it can reach 169.254.169.254 directly rather than sending the packets to the gateway.

More details why this happens and how you can stop this can be found on this blog.

https://rahulait.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/metadata-failure-with-ubuntu-desktop-on-openstack/

**Probable Reason2:-**

If you have a private-network and it is not connected to any "router", the gateway interface for that private-network will be down. For communicating to metadata service, the packets needs to be sent to gateway of network, which would not be reachable in this case and hence you would see these logs.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error raised because the L3 agent was down due to some corruption in the ini file. Check if there is an agent down in neutron:

```
openstack network agent list
```

Fix the issue (check the log at /var/log/neutron and restart the service)

```
service neutron-l3-agent restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on a node that was still running nova-network from a previous configuration.
The effect on the faulty node was this (bad):

```
# curl -v http://169.254.169.254/openstack
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 169.254.169.254...
* connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80: Connection refused
```

...instead of this (good):

```
# curl -v http://169.254.169.254/openstack
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 169.254.169.254...
* Immediate connect fail for 169.254.169.254: Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

If this is the case get rid of the legacy service on your node and enjoy.